# Javafx 8 - calendar GUI - casting Node as Pane?

Tags: javafx

Trying to iterate over a GridPane consisting of 35 Panes in order to create a GUI for a calendar. If anyone has any advice, please tell me.

```
@FXML
public GridPane table;

int col = monthStartsOnDay-1;
int max = 35 - col;
int row = 0;    
for (Node child : table.getChildren()) {
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(143,30);
    rectangle.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
    rectangle.setId(WEEK[col % 7] + "#" + row);
    child.add(rectangle, col, row); //the error comes here <------
    if(col % 6 == 0) {
        row++;
    } col++;
}
```

I guess casting the child as a Pane (the object it actually is) is not possible. But I need to make consistent changes to every single child of the GridPane (that is, every single Pane in every index of the GridPane) more or less all the time. So I need a way to do that, that isn't terrible like I am sure mine is!
Advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is casting the child as a Pane not possible?

Comment: No idea why, but by being a little cheeky, this worked
`Pane pane = (Pane) node;`
I guess creating a new instance like above solves my issue.

Comment: That doesn't create a new instance, it's just a cast.

Comment: Ah, okay. How is it different from `(Pane (node)).add(rectangle, col, row);` ? I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: That won't work because `Pane` doesn't define a method with that signature.

Comment: Ended up swapping to stackpanes and using the above cast. Do you know of a better way to do what I described in the initial post?

Comment: Honestly, it's not that clear to me what you're trying to do; there's not enough context. I would approach this quite differently - think about the data first and then make the UI a view of the data. So your calendar is a view of a month (probably represented by a [`java.util.time.YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html)) and each pane in the grid is a view of a day (`java.util.time.LocalDate`). The month view shouldn't have to worry about how to display the "day panes"; they determine those by knowing which day they are displaying.

Answer (score 0):

I've released some JavaFX controls (work in progress) for the new Date & Time API (JSR-310) .

The library is Open Source. Maybe you find it useful as a starting point.

You can read more about it here:

http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2013/04/drombler-commons-javafx-controls-for.html

http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2013/12/drombler-commons-date-and-time-controls.html

Current Javadoc: http://www.drombler.org/DromblerCommons/current/docs/site/drombler-commons-fx/drombler-commons-fx-time/apidocs/index.html

The library is available from Maven Central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drombler.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>drombler-commons-fx-time</artifactId>
    <version>0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

You can find some sample code here: http://sourceforge.net/p/drombler/drombler-commons/ci/default/tree/drombler-commons-fx/drombler-commons-fx-samples/drombler-commons-fx-samples-time/